# Compute row percentages in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Still kind of new to scala. I'm trying to compute percentages across rows in scala. Consider the following `df`:

```
val df = Seq(("word1", 25, 75),("word2", 15, 15),("word3", 10, 30)).toDF("word", "author1", "author2")

df.show

+-----+-------+-------+
| word|author1|author2|
+-----+-------+-------+
|word1|     25|     75|
|word2|     15|     15|
|word3|     10|     30|
+-----+-------+-------+
```

I know I can use a code like the following and get the expected output, however I was wondering if there was a better way to do it:

```
val df_2 = df
  .withColumn("total", $"author1" + $"author2")
  .withColumn("author1 pct", $"author1"/$"total")
  .withColumn("author2 pct", $"author2"/$"total")
  .select("word", "author1 pct", "author2 pct")

df_2.show

+-----+-----------+-----------+
| word|author1 pct|author2 pct|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|word1|       0.25|       0.75|
|word2|        0.5|        0.5|
|word3|       0.25|       0.75|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Bonus points to give it the percentage format with "%" and no decimals. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could just directly calculate and select the percentages, rather than using `.withColumn`, and use `concat` to add a `%` sign at the end:

```
val df2 = df.select(
    $"word", 
    concat(($"author1"*100/($"author1" + $"author2")).cast("int"), lit("%")).as("author1 pct"), 
    concat(($"author2"*100/($"author1" + $"author2")).cast("int"), lit("%")).as("author2 pct")
)

df2.show
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| word|author1 pct|author2 pct|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|word1|        25%|        75%|
|word2|        50%|        50%|
|word3|        25%|        75%|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

If you want to keep the numeric data types, then you can do

```
val df2 = df.select(
    $"word", 
    ($"author1"*100/($"author1" + $"author2")).cast("int").as("author1 pct"), 
    ($"author2"*100/($"author1" + $"author2")).cast("int").as("author2 pct")
)
```

Comment: If you use the concat function wouldn't that make the results strings rather than int?

Comment: A `%` sign cannot be part of an int @st_jimmy145

Comment: Yes, I understand that, my question was more like, with the solution above the results of df2 will be strings? I'm asking because then I shouldn't use that resulting df for further analysis

Comment: @st_jimmy145 in that case, you can see the second part of my edited answer. Does that help?